# I can not reboot my Glaxy s 9000

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, rom-flashing, boot

I was running CynogenMod 10 successfully on my Galaxy S 9000 till I got an update message which I unfortunately applied. It seems it could not get access to my apps installed to sdcard. Unfortunately, I did not make any backup from the old installed OS. Afterwards, I wanted to install a stable ROM following a guide on Internet, that I have to download the CynoGenMod ROM 9.0 on sdcard and then went to Recovery mode and installed it after pressing "Wide data/facatory reset".

It took hours till the Galaxy turned off. When I turned it on again, the Galaxy could reboot but I was not satisfied with it, so I went to ROM Manager and clicked Update to stable ROM and chose CynogenMod 10 again to install. Once applied it,  the Galaxy tried to reboot, showed the CynogenMOD logo and then went to recovery mode. It shows:

> CWM-based Recovery v6...
>
> reboot system now  install zip from sdcard
>
> install zip from sideload
>
> wipe data/factory reset 
>    wipe cache..
>
> backup and restore
>
> mount and storege
>
> advanced

Whenever I press "Reboot system now" it tries to reboot, show the CynogenMod logo and goes to Recovery mode again and so on.

As I said, due to the fact I did not backup the old functioning installed OS I can not make use of the feature shown in the menu "Backup and restore".

Any suggestion how to download and install  CynogenMod in this case?

Comment: You shouldn't use ROM manager. It is buggy and causes bricked devices.

Comment: it is now to late :(

Answer (score 1):

As you have access to the recovery partition, you should find an update zip that you can flash to it.

Most likely you will have one on your SD card still, if you updated using the CyanogenMod updater.

Using the recovery menu, navigate to `Install ZIP from SDCard` and select it. You will then have to find the update .zip file. It may be in a folder called `cmupdater` or something similar. If you have a folder like that, find a zip in that folder and select it to flash. Erase your data, and try and reboot the device.

If that doesn't work, then I am afraid I don't have any more ideas sorry.

Comment: I found update zip on the top of sdcard. When I selected it it failed telling me that an error in in that update.zip.!! Any other suggestion to install a new ROM through sideload for example?

Comment: The very same way: Download it on your PC, copy it to the card (e.g. via a card reader), and use the same method via "Install ZIP from SDCard". Check [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=Devices) for official builds.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this are the steps you followed:

```
    WIPE (wipe data/factory reset + wipe cache partition)
    Install the ROM from internal sdcard using ClockworkMod Recovery(Reinstall again the rom you want to use)
    Optionally:
    WIPE (wipe data/factory reset + wipe cache partition) again to be sure the partitions are ok
```

If not just reinstall again your cyanogen mod and it should work.